# How to get Route name from current URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on small project in React. I want to get Route name from the current URL in ReactJS.

I am currently using React-Router 3.2.0 and I want to solve this problem in React-router (3.2.0 ).

Comment: I think you can use `[PROPS].location.pathname`

Comment: @Kognise , Can you please explain more . How to apply in component

Comment: Are you using a class component or a function component?

Comment: I am using class based component

Comment: So probably `this.props.location.pathname`.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined` ? We may need to import something from `react-Router`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190637/discussion-between-kognise-and-jon).

Comment: Sure  Thanks !!!

Comment: Use window.location.pathname

Comment: @Baruch , Thank You for your comment . It working fine! but how to Ignore `/` ?

Comment: @Jon `window.location.pathname` won't work unless the user refreshes the page on the other route. I've sent some suggestions to the chat in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comments on the question, and the chat. You can't access `location` prop because the component you're on is not rendered by a `Route` component.
Easy way to solve this, at the top of your file, include the import:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
```

then, where you're exporting your component, wrap it in withRouter(... component here ...)
So for example, your `Routes` component export will look like:

```
export default withRouter(connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {}
    )(Routes))
```

You'll then be able to access `this.props.location` which will have a value, `pathname` (`this.props.location.pathname`) which will be the full route, minus the basePath.